# Why can't I connect to a bash shell on an Azure Container Instance from my local machine?

Tags: bash, azure, azure-container-instances

I am trying to launch a shell in an Azure container instance from my local machine and it keep printing out this weird messages but never launches the shell:

```
az container exec --resource-group myrsg --subscription <subs_id> --name <name_container_instance> --container-name console --exec-command "/bin/bash"
```

This is what is thrown on the screen when i execute this:

```
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\websocket/_app.py", line 345, in _callback
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/container/custom.py", line 644, in _on_ws_msg
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\colorama/ansitowin32.py", line 41, in write
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\colorama/ansitowin32.py", line 162, in write
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\colorama/ansitowin32.py", line 184, in write_and_convert
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\colorama/ansitowin32.py", line 246, in convert_osc
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\websocket/_app.py", line 345, in _callback
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/container/custom.py", line 644, in _on_ws_msg
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\colorama/ansitowin32.py", line 41, in write
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\colorama/ansitowin32.py", line 162, in write
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\colorama/ansitowin32.py", line 184, in write_and_convert
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\colorama/ansitowin32.py", line 246, in convert_osc
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\websocket/_app.py", line 345, in _callback
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/container/custom.py", line 644, in _on_ws_msg
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\colorama/ansitowin32.py", line 41, in write
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\colorama/ansitowin32.py", line 162, in write
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\colorama/ansitowin32.py", line 184, in write_and_convert
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\colorama/ansitowin32.py", line 246, in convert_osc
```

I have no idea whats happening here. How do i get a bash shell working on my local machine?

Comment: Reinstall Azure CLI

Comment: Your command is correct. After reinstalling the CLI and rebooting your system, double-check that the container has a bash shell. Some stripped-down containers have no shell or only the Bourne shell.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary The reinstall worked. Thanks. Post that as the answer and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your Azure CLI has been corrupted as your command is perfectly fine - try [reinstalling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli) it.